# Changing animation of Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-navigation, flutter-state, flutter-routes

I need to reload the initstate after pop back.I put method below into WillPopScope.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
          NewHomeScreen.routeName,
          (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
        );
```

The problem is that this navigation is going left to right.It is not giving pop feeling.How can I change the animation right to left.Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/317b620b-1c29-4c81-a5d1-bcced807e6de/y

Comment: @omarhatem Can you help me how can i make like a pop? Which arguments do I need to change?